# Should I convert methods which doesn’t use this to static ones in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I start using ESlint, and 
when I create a method like that in React component:

```
getWholeQUantityProducts(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj)
      .reduce((sum, key) => sum + parseFloat(obj[key]), 0);
  }
```

it warns me that **`"If a class method does not use this, it can safely be made a static function"`**.

then I made it static  and put it before a constructor:

```
  static getWholeQUantityProducts(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj)
      .reduce((sum, key) => sum + parseFloat(obj[key]), 0);
  }
```

Now to call this method inside my component I write `this.constructor.methodName`.

I haven't seen yet that anyone recommends or uses such stuff in react tutorials.

So should I turning off this eslint rule? or write static method if doesn't contains **`this`**.

Answer (score 0):

The ESLint rules are best-practices authored by the creator. In this case it looks more like a utility method and not class dependent so it would make sense to export it into a utility class as a static method.

But to call it with `this.constructor.methodName` is weird. E.g. should look like this

```
export class Utils {

    public static getWholeQUantityProducts(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj)
      .reduce((sum, key) => sum + parseFloat(obj[key]), 0);
  }
}
```

And you would call it with `Utils.getWholeQUantityProducts(obj)`.

Comment: Isn't it public by default? (so there's no need to write the *public* keyword)

Comment: @Kinduser You are right. Seems like it's set to public as default.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, private and public in JS are reserved for future and do not work today.